# does golang compiler use constant folding?

Tags: go, compiler-optimization, constantfolding

just wondering if "go" compiler uses any sort of optimization such as constant folding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding

searched through google but couldn't find the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have anything concrete in mind? If you're just looking for a "yes" or "no", the answer is "yes" - but that information alone is next to useless, as there are many corner cases where it may or may not happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Constant folding - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)
>
> Constant folding is the process of recognizing and evaluating constant
>   expressions at compile time rather than computing them at runtime.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)
>
> Constant expressions may contain only constant operands and are
>   evaluated at compile time.

---

> [Package big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/)
>
> ```
> import "math/big"
> ```
>
> Package big implements arbitrary-precision arithmetic (big numbers).

---

Go constant expressions are evaluated at compile time. The Go gc compiler, written in Go, uses package `big` to evaluate numeric constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a simple program: eg.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(12345*1000)
}
```

And now compile it to assembly

```
go tool compile -S examle.go
```

And now find 12345 in the result and you will have an answer.

Comment: Appreciate the example, but this doesn't give a "yes" or "no" answer to the question.